# where can i get cakephp portal parts

Tags: php, cakephp

where can i get cakephp portal parts - code that could be used for portals,

for example - forum part, user login, search forms, user admin parts, etc

Answer (score 0):

Sparkplug is a decent one for user management: http://blogfreakz.com/cakephp/cakephp-user-management-plugin/

Start looking for others here:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/
http://cakeforge.org/

Now, one reason I'm moving away from cake and into Rails is the lack of community-contributed plugins.