# Is there such a thing as Cakephp "user management" plugin script

Tags: php, cakephp

is there anywhere such script that includes a cakephp user management part,

view - registration form ( for example allowing to enter: first name, surname, email, user address, user phone number, last login date etc. )

sends confirmation to email - about registration

inserts users data into mysql tables (users id, etc.) and blocks duplicate entries to users tables

or does other similar tasks

etc.

if there is no such plugin then may be someone can send the custom made scripts

Answer (score 1):

[Spark Plug Cakephp user management plugin](http://blogfreakz.com/cakephp/cakephp-user-management-plugin/)
or Authake or ...

But its easy to program such a plugin by yourself.

BTW: This question was answered in [one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484645/where-can-i-get-cakephp-portal-parts)